# How to replace MVC3 Grid column ActionLink with <a> tag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

How to replace MVC3 Grid column **ActionLink** with `<a>` tag?

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "delete-button" } ), style: "column-action")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the signature will allow an IHtmlString.  Untested.

```
grid.Column(
      format: (item) => Html.Raw("<a href='/delete/"
                                 + item.ID 
                                 + "' class='delete-button'>Delete</a>"),
      style: "column-action"
);
```